# Reset Akeneo Admin password from command line?

Tags: akeneo

I'm new to Akeneo and have just set up a docker environment with version 1.4.12.  The site is working, but I have copied over our production database and cannot log in now.  I can see the oro_user table with the salt and passwords, but need to reset the admin password for my development environment.  Our administrator who knows the password is away for a while (Xmas season).

I found the `php app/console security:encode-password` utility.  This outputs values to be inserted in the database but these do not seem to be working.  The generated password hash is in the form of `mypassword{HASHSTRING}` - and the HASHSTRING is matching the salt value (which seems wrong).  I've tried the exact generated password value and only the HASHSTRING within the braces.  These values are put into the corresponding database fields.

So far no luck.  Any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you cannot login is because your secret parameter in app/config/parameters.yml is not the same between your development environment and your production environment.

You can also use our reset password feature available here: http://yourinstall/user/reset-request

Comment: Thanks.  The key issue makes sense if I had a new database.  We copied the DB and source files from production though so the keys should be fine.  The reset-request routine requires the mail system to be properly set up, I think.  The dev environement is not, and we don't want to change the password on the production environment.  It's an option to keep in mind though.  We were able to get around the problem - the admin answered our texts to him.

Comment: Nice. FYI, you can get the pending mails to send in a folder by configuring swiftmailer like that: https://symfony.com/doc/current/email/spool.html

Answer (score 0):

Try running app/console server:run and logging through localhost:8000

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12583741)

Comment: It provides. After importing sql dump from server akeneo starts to return error to what ever credentials through local apache or nginx server connection but doesn't using php built in server